# Expectation and pdf of a function of a random variable $Y = g(X)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Consider a random variable $X\sim\text{Uniform}[e, e^2]$ and define the new random variable $Y = \ln(X)$.

A) How do we compute $E(Y)$, using the theorem that states that $$E(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f_{X}(x) dx$$

B) How do you compute $E(Y)$ by computing the probability density function of $Y$ first?

Comment: You mean $E[g(X)]$, not $E[g(x)]$.

Comment: yes @parsiad, my apologies. Edited.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) Take $g(x)=\ln(x)$ to get 
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\ln(X)\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln(x)f_{X}(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln(x)\frac{\boldsymbol{1}_{(e,e^{2})}(x)}{e^{2}-e}dx\\
=\frac{1}{e^{2}-e}\int_{e}^{e^{2}}\ln(x)dx=\frac{e^{2}}{e^{2}-e}.
\end{multline*}

(B) If $1<y<2$, then
\begin{multline*}
F_{Y}(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(\ln(X)\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq e^{y})=\int_{-\infty}^{e^{y}}f_{X}(x)dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{e^{y}}\frac{\boldsymbol{1}_{(e,e^{2})}(x)}{e^{2}-e}dx=\frac{1}{e^{2}-e}\int_{e}^{e^{y}}dx=\frac{e^{y}-e}{e^{2}-e}.
\end{multline*}
Taking derivatives, it follows that
$$
f_{Y}(y)=\frac{e^{y}\boldsymbol{1}_{(1,2)}(y)}{e^{2}-e}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf_{Y}(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\frac{e^{y}\boldsymbol{1}_{(1,2)}(y)}{e^{2}-e}dy=\frac{1}{e^{2}-e}\int_{1}^{2}ye^{y}dy=\frac{e^{2}}{e^{2}-e}.
$$
This is the same answer as was obtained in part (A).